# How can I run a file on a web server via a web page

Tags: javascript, php, batch-file

I'm so tired of searching and not getting the correct answer.

So my question is.

How can I run a file on the web server via the web site.

Explanation.

I have a Windows server 2012 with IIS installed. I have PHP 7 installed.
I want to create a website where a use can click on a button "Launch notepad.bat",
and when the button is clicked on the website, The notepad.bat should run on the server.
Then if possible, I want to read the result of the results in the command prompt back to the array in PHP.

Real life application example.

There is a startServer.bat in the folder, the .bat starts the minecraft server. The user clicks on the launch button on the web page and the startServer.bat should now be running. Then a box open on the webpage that shows all the lines inside the command prompt that is currently running via JavaScript

I do have extensive knowledge of PHP and JavaScript, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working. Ignore security risks for now.

Some code:

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['RunNote'])) {
    exec('START ./startServer.bat');
}
```

html

```
<form action=" <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> " method="POST" name="noteForm">
    <input type="submit" name="RunNote" value="Launch Notepad">
</form>
```

Then when I click the button, I get a 500 - Internal server error

Comment: `I get a 500 - Internal server error` - can you check the PHP error log for more information on what the error was?

Comment: I looked in the error log and found no errors. When I click on the button, the web page just say connecting for 5 minutes and then the 500 internal server error occurs

Comment: I changed the exec to  exec('START notepad'); 
Then the Notepad and the Console Window Host is launched. The Console Window Host is under the Windows Processes section and Notepad is under the background processes section. Although the notepad is being opened, I cannot interact with it. It just sits in the background.

Comment: It is impossible to interact with notepad because PHP launch it in hidden session 0 with IIS user logged in. If it is command line app which output to standard output it is possible but if you need to run GUI application it is impossible.

Comment: 500 is caused because nothing don't close your notepad. It crashes on some server timeout. I there are some timeout for exec command.

Comment: Ooh Okay I understand.. So if I run the Command Line server in the background, I can issue commands like '/restart' or '/stop' via PHP and the Command Prompt will obey?
Can I also read the output of the Command Prompt via PHP?

Comment: I can use fread to get the lines. But I only can read one line at a time. How would I get all the data in the command prompt and know when the command script is done?